# Two wherehas in a Laravel Eloquent query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following query, simplified below.

```
$property = Property::whereHas('features', function ($q1) use ($features) {
            $q1->where(function ($sub) use ($features) {
                $sub->whereIn('features.FeatureID', $features);
            });
            $q1->groupBy('PropertyID');
            $q1->having('count(*)', '=', count($features));
        })
        ->whereHas('Week', function ($q) use ($nights) {
            $q->where(function ($sub) use ($nights) {
                $sub->whereIn('priceAvailDate', $nights);
            });
            $q->groupBy('PropertyID');
            $q->having('count(*)', '=', count($nights));
        })
        ->get();
```

If I take one whereHas out, I get the expected collection returned. If I take the other out I get the expected result.It is when they are together I have nothing returned. I assume it is down to having two count(*). I know I have data where both whereHas is true.

SQL output is

```
select * from `tblproperties` where (select count(*) from `features` inner 
join `propertyfeatures` on `features`.`featureid` = 
`propertyfeatures`.`FeatureID` where `propertyfeatures`.`PropertyID` = 
`tblproperties`.`PropertyID` and (`features`.`FeatureID` in (?)) group by 
`PropertyID` having `count(*)` = ?) >= 1 and (select count(*) from 
`tblpriceavail` where `tblpriceavail`.`propertyID` =     `tblproperties`.`PropertyID` 
and (`priceAvailDate` in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)) group by 
`PropertyID` having `count(*)` = ?) >= 1
```

Fixed, although not 100% sure why. Using havingRaw instead of having worked.

i.e. changing the $q->having('count(*)', '=', count($nights));

to $q->havingRaw('count(*) = ' . count($nights));

Comment: can you `dd(DB::getQueryLog())` and show the output

Comment: What would be my use statement? I tried use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB; and I get an empty array.

Comment: Change your ->get() to ->toSql(); Maybe you will find your error.

Comment: That worked. Will paste in SQL above.

Comment: The two `WHERE` conditions generated must be both true for each item. Meaning a property must have both associated entries in the `propertyfeatures` table as well as the `tblpriceavail` table, for it to be returned by the query. Is that the case, or do you want all entries that have either one or the other, but not necessarily both?

Comment: @bogdan That's correct, need both to be true.